# Android - Save list of object property with specific key on Firebase

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's consider a "UserBean" with a property "emails" that is an `ArrayList<EmailBean>`.

When saved in **Firebase** it's like :

```
"users" : {
   "$userID" : {
        "emails" : [
            "0" : {
                "type" : "first",
                "address" : "google@google.com",
                "private" : true
            },
            "1" : {
                "type" : "second",
                "address" : "firebase@firebase.com",
                "private" : false"
            }
        ],
        "name" : "Mitch"
    }
}
```

So is it possible to achieve something like this :

```
"users" : {
   "$userID" : {
        "emails" : [
            "first" : {
                "address" : "google@google.com",
                "private" : true
            },
            "second" : {
                "address" : "firebase@firebase.com",
                "private" : false
            }
        ],
        "name" : "Mitch"
    }
}
```

I would prefer to not having to save each address one at a time.

Maybe there's an annotation to tells **Firebase** to use this property as a key ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you using the code below:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference emailsRef = rootRef.child("users").child(userId).child("emails");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String type = ds.child("type").getValue(String.class);
            ds.child("type").getRef().getParent().setValue(type);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
emailsRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

What have i tried with this code? So in order to achieve what you want, first of all we got the value of your `type` key. Then we get a step up in the tree and set the partent with the value of your `type` key for each particular node.

Having the value of type in stead of `0, 1 and so on`, to get the work done, just remove the `type key`, from each node using `removeValue()` method directly on the reference.